# How to achieve the IG TV bottom swipe panel in React Native or Swift?

Tags: swift, react-native, swipe

Please see the video below to see which feature.

https://streamable.com/49k8p

When you swipe your finger from bottom to top a panel opens with other videos, we just want to learn what is that called or what library is it? We simply can't find resources about that to achieve a similar feature in our React Native app.

Sorry for the newbie question!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any library, but with `react-native-gesture-handler` it easy easy to implement! Here what I did in my previous project:

```
let onGestureEvent = Animated.event([
  {
      nativeEvent: {
         translationY: height,
         },
  },
]);

let translateY = new Animated.Value(-300)

let onHandlerStateChange = ({nativeEvent}) => {
    if (nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      if (nativeEvent.translationY > 0) {
        Animated.spring(translateY, {toValue: 300}).start(() => {
          isExpanded = false;
          height.setOffset(0);
          height.setValue(0);
        });
      } else {
        Animated.spring(translateY, {toValue: -300}).start(() => {
          isExpanded = true;
          height.setOffset(-300);
          height.setValue(0);
        });
      }
    }
  };

return (<>
   <PanGestureHandler 
        onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}>
      <YourVideoPlayer/>
   </PanGestureHandler>

   <Animated.View style={[styles.row, {transform: [{translateY}]}]}>
      <YourVideosComponent/>
   </Animated.View>
</>)
```

You have to wrap your video player with `PanGestureHandler` and wrap your panel with `absolute` positioned `Animated.View`. Let me know if you do not understand something

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, your code makes really sense. I actually went away and checked RN gesture handler library and it seems exactly what we were looking for! Thanks again gonna try a sample and report

Comment: So did you check! The question still remains unanswered!

Comment: Indeed we did and it came out quite good, i'll try to post the results as a reply here as soon as I can.